# How do i correctly iterate through these html image elements and load a different, random image on each more concisely?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, variables

i am attempting to code a simple game involving guessing the hearthstone card to which the presented flavor text belongs. Eventually a button will be linked to this function to advance in the game, but i have not gotten that far.

I have created 4 image elements and created a unique randCard variable for each to select an object from an array of cards. I tried with a single variable for this originally but it loaded the same image for all elements.

Then i wanted to print text from one of the 4 random objects, so i put the randCard variables in an array themselves, and made a new variable. Each image id is updated with it's own randCard currently, and i was attempting to simplify this code without success.

This is the only way i have been able to make it function as i intend it to, however i am relatively new to working with JS and JQuery (which is why i am doing this project, to learn) and would love if someone with some experience could explain how i could make this code less repetitive.

Thanks in advance for any assistance you may be willing to provide.

```
     var cards = []; //initializing array for card objects

 $.getJSON("cards.collectible.js", function(data) {        //card data is pulled from here

    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        var imgPath = 'hscards/' + value.name + '.png';
        cards.push({"name": value.name, "flavor": value.flavor, "path": imgPath, "set": value.set});
    });

    console.log(cards); 

});



$(function(){ //block 1 variable determine a random object from the cards array
             // block 2 updates each corresponding element

var randCard1 = cards[Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length)];
var randCard2 = cards[Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length)];
var randCard3 = cards[Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length)];
var randCard4 = cards[Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length)];
var randCards = [randCard1, randCard2, randCard3, randCard4];
var randFlav = randCards[Math.floor(Math.random() * randCards.length)];

    $("#card1").hide().attr("src", randCards[0].path).attr("alt", randCards[0].name).fadeIn();
    $("#card2").hide().attr("src", randCards[1].path).attr("alt", randCards[1].name).fadeIn();
    $("#card3").hide().attr("src", randCards[2].path).attr("alt", randCards[2].name).fadeIn();
    $("#card4").hide().attr("src", randCards[3].path).attr("alt", randCards[3].name).fadeIn();
    $("#flavTxt").hide().html(randFlav.flavor).fadeIn();

    console.log(randFlav.flavor);


});
```

Comment: You could use a [for statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestion of a for loop. I re-wrote it with this loop successfully.

```
 var cards = [];

 $.getJSON("cards.collectible.js", function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        var imgPath = 'hscards/' + value.name + '.png';
        cards.push({"name": value.name, "flavor": value.flavor, "path": imgPath, "set": value.set});
    });



var randCard0;var randCard1;var randCard2;var randCard3;
var randCards = [randCard0, randCard1, randCard2, randCard3];

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        randCards[i] = cards[Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length)];
        console.log(randCards[i].name);
        $("#card" + i).hide().attr("src", randCards[i].path).attr("alt", 
        randCards[i].name).fadeIn();
};

var randFlav = randCards[Math.floor(Math.random() * randCards.length)].flavor;          

$("#flavTxt").hide().html(randFlav).fadeIn();

console.log(randFlav);

});
```

Comment: Instead of creating the randCards, you can just use a single variable inside of the for loop that uses the random card and assign the source to that

Comment: Thank you for your input! I was just figuring this out as you commented, and i am glad to know i was on the right track. I have learned a lot about how to take advantage of these loops.